# Android manifest configuration?

Tags: android

What do I need to put in my android manifest file to:

1. support all screen sizes.
2. Hide the icons in the android bottom nav bar on 3.0, i know you cannot remove the bar, but you can hide the icons.

Answer (score 4):

For the first point, you can try to play with this, for example:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

as explained in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html) and this [other link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).